# access endpoint protected by oauth using wso2 api manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

In a given use case, there is an API is hosted on client-side(**say Y**) and is protected by OAuth at their end(**Y's**). Another client(**say X**) has an API published on WSO2 API Manager 3.0.0(on-premise setup) with **Y's API as backend endpoint**.
How to configure an endpoint in WSO2 API Manager at X's end wherein authentication/authorization of endpoint Y's API happens using Y's OAuth by calling Y's OAuth server as part of an endpoint call (not by exclusively/directly calling Y's OAuth Server to get access token).

Please advise on how to achieve this use case.

Comment: checkout this blog https://medium.com/@menakajayawardena/wso2-how-to-using-oauth2-protected-back-ends-with-api-manager-5d7e234c61c

Comment: @naoko ... tried this on api manager 3.0.0, but it doesn't seem to send the request to the local (wso2) token server as well. Please advise.

Comment: @Diligent what is the error you are getting in the server logs of Gateway and Key manager when calling the API?